# Flutter adding column scroll at fullscreen with listview builder

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll

I want to create a canvas that the entire column is slideable. But the way I did (code below) in the listview.builder the scroll doesn't work. How could I resolve this? I need the full screen scroll to work.

I also tried using Expanded in the listview, it would work but the top text and bottom container are fixed, I don't want that.

I'm new to mobile development, kinda confused hahaha.
The code:

```
class _CursosPageState extends State<CursosPage> {
  int count = 4;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           children: [
             SizedBox(height: 15),
             Text(
               'text text text',
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
             ),
             // Expanded(
             //   child:
             ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: count,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    height: 150,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                   );
                  },
                ),
               // ),
               Center(
                 child: Container(
                   height: 150,
                   width: 300,
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     color: Colors.red,
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                   ),
                  ),
                )
               ],
             ),
            ),
          ),
         );
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use  `SingleChildScrollView`, You can use ListView as Toplevel widget.

```dart
class _CursosPageState extends State<CursosPage> {
  int count = 4;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 15),
                Text(
                  'text text text',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    height: 150,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 300,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or have fixed Text on top

```dart
class _CursosPageState extends State<CursosPage> {
  int count = 4;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Text(
              'text text text',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: count,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    height: 150,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 150,
                width: 300,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Once you are flexible with listView you can use [CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) for complex scenario

Comment: I need to use listview because of build context, and the ListView.builder() constructor creates items as they scroll on the screen.  In the second code, it would not be useful to leave the text fixed, I would like to scroll the entire screen

Comment: Using `shrinkWrap: true` isnot a good choice , Also once you are familiar with theses, use CustomScrollView

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, you want this:

```
 int count = 4;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView(
        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(height: 15),
          const Text(
            'text text text',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: count,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    height: 150,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 300,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Try this one, it should solve your problem.

Comment: nice it works, it was exactly what i wanted. Thanks